# Tabcontrol in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2005, how do you disable or make read only a particular tabpage?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see, for now, is using the **TabControl.Selecting** control event and manage everything by code.

Just turn **e.Cancel** to true to block access to a specific tabpage.